# Convert using unixtimestamp to Date

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a field in a dataframe that has a column with date like 1632838270314 as an example

I want to convert it to date like 'yyyy-MM-dd' I have this so far but it doesn't work:

```
date = df['createdOn'].cast(StringType())
df = df.withColumn('date_key',unix_timestamp(date),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast("date"))
```

createdOn is the field that derives the date_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `unix_timestamp()` is for converting a timestamp or date *string* into the number seconds since 01-01-1970 ("epoch"). I understand that you want to do the opposite.

Your example value "1632838270314" seems to be milliseconds since epoch.

Here you can simply `cast` it after converting from milliseconds to seconds:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sql_context.createDataFrame([
    Row(unix_in_ms=1632838270314),
])
(
    df
    .withColumn('timestamp_type', (F.col('unix_in_ms')/1e3).cast('timestamp'))
    .withColumn('date_type', F.to_date('timestamp_type'))
    .withColumn('string_type', F.col('date_type').cast('string'))
    .withColumn('date_to_unix_in_s', F.unix_timestamp('string_type', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    .show(truncate=False)
)
# Output
+-------------+-----------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|unix_in_ms   |timestamp_type         |date_type |string_type|date_to_unix_in_s|
+-------------+-----------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|1632838270314|2021-09-28 16:11:10.314|2021-09-28|2021-09-28 |1632780000       |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

You can combine the conversion into a single command:

```py
df.withColumn('date_key', F.to_date((F.col('unix_in_ms')/1e3).cast('timestamp')).cast('string'))
```

Comment: Is it posssible to convert to yymmdd without creating any extra columns?  like to create one column then do the conversion?

Comment: Similar to what I did

Comment: Sure, you can simply "overwrite" the columns by setting the same name in every line, or merge the statements into one. From your question it is still not completely clear to me what you actually want to have in the end: a column of type "date" or a string column with strings of format "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: I want a string of yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @user3476582 : please accept my answer if it solved your problem